# Is there a boolean function to know if select multiple have several option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to know if there is a function - with a boolean return - to know if a select multiple contain more than one option selected in JS/JQuery.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to select all the selected options and use `length` on it to get the number of options selected.

```
var multipleSelected = $('select option:selected').length > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks.. It's.. Obvious...